# Concatenating strings in R

Tags: r

I have the following list.

```
l=list("home car train", "remote TV helicopter", "grenade hello")
```

My goal is to set the words in each item of the list in an alphabetical order. 
Meaning, the requested result in this case would be:

```
"car home train", "helicopter TV remote", "hello grenade"
```

At first I used *strsplit* to separate the words in each string:

```
l2<-lapply(l,function(x){as.character(sort(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "\\ "))))})
```

After this step I'm not sure how to concatenate the different sorted values each item to the requested list format. (no luck  so far with *paste* function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split the words, sort and paste back together

```
lapply(strsplit(unlist(l), " "),
       function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=" "))
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "car home train"

[[2]]
[1] "helicopter remote TV"

[[3]]
[1] "grenade hello"
```

Use `unlist(l)` to convert `l` from a list to a character vector, which is required by `strsplit`.

`strsplit` will output a list where each element is a vector of the words in an element of `l`. `sort` each vector, then `paste` together all its elements by setting `collapse=" "`.